# Where in BCL code the implementation for operators && and & on booleans can be found?

Tags: c#, boolean, operator-overloading, base-class-library

You know, when I read about difference between `&` and `&&` operators, that can be operates with Boolean, I have become interested in implementation of those operators.

But when I looked at the `Boolean` type, I did not find it any implementation for those operators.

Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can find such basic operators in the source code of the BCL. I expect this to compile to direct instructions to the CLR or even more directly.

Comment: Could you even suggest how can I get it?

Comment: I am using dotPeek for decompiling some .NET sources,
and of course ildasm for disassembling PE an DLLs.

So, which way do you describe ?
Could you explain what files should I disassemble ?

Comment: The core files of the CLR, not the ones you have compiled. That source is not made public.